# Create tag synonyms: synonyms-синонимы

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

It was brought to my attentions that `synonyms` and `синонимы` are not tag synonyms.  Can someone with the right permissions please set this up?

Comment: +1 Went to meta to ask for the same.

Comment: @Artemix You should be able to suggest this.  On the original question, click on "синонимы" tag and enter "synonyms" as the suggestion at the bottom.

Comment: No, I can't, I even cannot vote for a synonym: "Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms.

Comment: Argh... I have 2500, but, apparently, not on synonyms tag :)

Answer (score 1):

The tag synonyms had been created but they were the opposite of what they should have been, so I swapped them and merged them so... it's all done. :)